# Bug using two Monitors with different resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have a very confusing problem.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with 2 monitors
My main monitor (15.6") has a resolution of 1920x1080 and my second one is 28" with  a 4k resolution.
When I'm using my two monitors with different resolution, then i can't use the menu bar in programs which are displayed on my primary monitor (15.6")
I'm also not able to put icons on my primary screen and I can't rightclick in programs which are located on my primary screen
When moving these programs on my 2nd monitor everything works as it should

Now when i change the resolution of my 28" screen to 1920x1080 then everything works as intended on both screens

Does someone has a clue what could be the culprit of this problem?

EDIT:
Noticed a strange behaviour
my screens are arranged in this way

```
+----------------+
|                |
|                |+---------+
|                ||         |
|                ||         |
+----------------++---------+
```

in this way the problems described occur on my right screen
but when i move my smaller monitor up to the upper border of my big screen like this

```
+----------------++---------+
|                ||         |
|                ||         |
|                |+---------+
|                |
+----------------+
```

everything works as it should

EDIT 2:
This is the output of

```
lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)
```

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Pegatron Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
    Memory at dd000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

I don't know if it's necessary but my laptop has another graphic card

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Pegatron GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 132
    Memory at de000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at df000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: does anyone has any idea?
I'm really stuck with this problem

Comment: I don't have an idea, but I chipped in 50 quatloos to draw attention to this. That's why it's a good idea to confirm useful and good answers to questions; it give us a bank of gold-pressed latinum we can give away to help solve stuff we're personally clueless about. This also may be a reportable bug; those end up in https://launchpad.net . Have you checked there for a similar bug report? Lastly, what happens when you boot from a Kubuntu 19.10 LiveUSB? Does the issue replicate?

Comment: What happens when you boot from a Kubuntu 19.10 LiveUSB? Does the issue replicate?

Comment: I didn't find any similar topic on launchpad.net 
but I tried the Ubuntu 19.10 Live-CD and everything worked as it should 
no matter how the desktops are arranged
The menu bar is clickable again and i could move some icons to my main desktop

Comment: How about the 18.04 LiveDVD or LiveUSB? We're narrowing down possible causes.

Comment: In fact it is important that you're using two graphic cards. One (Intel) is for energy saving and one (Nvidia) is for 3D performance use ... I'll guess the behavior is visible if you are in performance mode and I've would take a look at the `nvidia-settings` (search for something like 'profiles') ... Or at first use the free nouveau driver, to get a little nearer to the cause.